# append int ordinal to str in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

How can I append an int containing an ordinal number to a str in Python 2.7?
Example:

```
number = 10 # You can assume its smaller than 128
mystr = "abc"

mystr = mystr+number # Gives error
assert mystr == "abc\x0A"
```

Of course, "mystr%d"%number or mystr+str(number) won't work, they would give "abc10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the built-in function `chr`:

```
number = 10 
mystr = "abc"

mystr = mystr + chr(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import struct
mystr = mystr+struct.pack("b",number)
```

satisfies the assertion.